# my https does not work just show plane words

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Some one was complaining about HTTPS which is Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure. my main question is not what the HTTPS is but I am just asking sharp about the frailer of using https for wordpress website . I have done all the googling, tried to learn from other questions and I showed what I have tried. Simply when I use https://myweb.com
it gives me plane text and none of the pages shows
I did click on permalink and save and I went to all the steps below but it still does not work . let me know if you have any other question

I got the latest version of the theme (twinty fourtheen) I gave access to it

```
total 8
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   31 Aug 17 12:29 index.php
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root   56 Aug 17 14:06 plugins
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root   57 Aug 17 14:08 themes
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root   47 Aug 17 14:08 upgrade
drwxrwxrwx. 11 root root 4096 Aug 17 12:29 uploads
```

I went to setting --> permalink then I save and I added this to .htaccess
Once I saved the permalink, it gaves me this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

i also read online and I found this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

so I tried both but they didnt work

I have set the https for `WordPress Address (URL)` and `Site Address (URL)`
I also have added this to the wp-config

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
   $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

I cannot think of anything else. is there someone who had some idea?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In the title you state that "https does not work" (whatever that means exactly ...), but what does that have to do with wordpress or a theme? And what does the additional "just show plane words" in the title actually mean?  What does "they didn't work" mean _exactly_ ?

Comment: @arkascha https means Hypertext transfer protocol secure which is essensital for a website security. It is important to link a website for it. This question is for those who are familar with website design or migration or those that have info about wordpress or htaccess or other tags. i tried to explain all , if you are familar with computer language , when one tell you it gives plane page means no figure, no data no info . let me know if it is unclear and I will do my best to send some link and in google

Comment: @arkascha I just added more information so that people can understand what I ask. if anything else in your opinion is not clear please let me know and I do my best to make it clear

Comment: Em... OK. Sorry if I confused you. Did you see my reputation here? Believe me, I do know what https is and how a web application works. That really is not what I asked :-)

Comment: Let me ask in another way: what do you mean by "plane text"? Maybe "plain text"? So another visualization of the content you expected? Or other content? What is it you actually see? And why should that depend on the protocol used to load a web page from your wordpress application, be it http or https? Both transport the same content ...

Comment: Can we assume that if you disable https for the wordpress installation, that you can then see the content ("the pages") the way you expected, so not as "plain text"? Or is it broken too when you load the content via normal http protocol?

Comment: Please add an example of what you actually see, which you describe as "plain text". I suspect that is an error message, not the actual page content. If so then it would be important to know that message ...